# Is there a .NET class for hotkeys that can be matched against incoming KeyEventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, plugins, hotkeys

Basically I have run-time loaded class that looks like this:

```
[Plugin("Plugin name")]
class PluginActions
{
  [Action("Flip Normals")
  public void FlipNormals()
  {
    // code ....
  }

  [Action("Export .X object")
  public void ExportX()
  {
    // code ....
  }
}
```

This basically adds buttons to the form with the onClick eventhandlers set up.

Now I would like to specify HOTKEYs in the same style using attributes:

```
[Plugin("Plugin name")]
class PluginActions
{
  [Action("Flip Normals", Hotkey = "Ctrl+N")
  public void FlipNormals()
  {
    // code ....
  }

  [Action("Export .X object", Hotkey = "Ctrl+E")
  public void ExportX()
  {
    // code ....
  }
}
```

The question is, how to represent and capture the hotkeys? As strings? Is there perhaps a class for that?

```
void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // reflection magic ...

  foreach(var action in actionAttributes)
  {
    string action_hotkey = action.hotkey;

    /**** How to match KeyEventArgs against action_hotkey? ****/
  }
}
```

Is there a .net helper class for dealing with hotkeys?

Or do i have to roll out my own hotkey class of some kind?

What is the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the Keys enumeration in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. Then for hotkey Ctrl+A  you can write something like this:

```
public class Action : Attribute {
  public Keys HotKey {get;set;} 
}


[Action(HotKey = (Keys.Control | Keys.A))]
public void MyMethod() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

KeyEventArgs contains KeyData property, which is of value Keys, which is a flag, meaning that it can be this:

`Keys keys = Keys.Control | Keys.F;` (your hotkey)

If you define your hotkeys (atribute) this way (not with string) you can then compare the Keys instead of strings.